# Crashing Problems with MacBook Pro 16 5600 Graphics 64GB RAM

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport

Not sure if this is the place to ask, but I've got the latest Intel Macbook Pro with 64GB of RAM and the 5600 Graphics.  When I'm at work (most of the time), I run with the MacBook closed and have 3 external monitors plugged in.  2-4K and 1-2560x1440.

I've got a CalDigit port extender with the following configuration:

- USB-C connected to MacBook (of course)
- DisplayPort to 4K Monitor
- Ethernet plugged into GB Cable
- 120V Power

On my MacBook, I have 3 USB-C devices connected

- CalDigit Thunderbolt 3 Cable
- DisplayPort Adapter to 4K Monitor
- 87 Watt Power (though not necessary as CalDigit also supplies power)
- HDMI Adapter To 2560x1440 monitor

What is happening is several times a day my monitors will just all fade out and fade back on.  When this happens, it often happens 3 or 4 times in a row then goes back to normal.  Sometimes though, I'll get a full panic crash (report points to many different things but not helpful to me)

First, any bells ringing for anyone?

Second, are there any good port replicators or EGPU's that can do a better job and just manage all 3 monitors for me?  Maybe having less plugged into the MacBook itself would help.

BTW, I have turned graphics switching off, and I've tried running without and with my extra power directly to the MacBook with the same crashing results.

I do have AppleCare, but I know they will be no help.